# React Native AwesomeProject error: could not find source file at index.ios.js

Tags: react-native

I did a fresh installation of latest React Native and tried the AwesomeProject. But I got a red screen on iOS 6 simulator with the following error message:

```
could not find source file at index.ios.js
:0
```

I used the following command to create the default project:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject2
```

And I didn't change a single line of code. Is this an installation issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted my machine and it worked fine now.